# RabbitMQ, wainting while all 10 workers will execute

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

In RabbitMQ I would like to make 'Worker Queue' pattern.
Each worker should return some value.

But main thing I need to have, is to run a pack of tasks to set of workers and have an event or message or something like this, when these tasks are all executed.

Hot to implement it?

For example, I send 10 URLS to workers. Each URL is a page in paginated web site. So I want to retrieve all these pages, once they are all retrieved I have to do something with them. But main purpose is to have them all!

Comment: This is a rather opinionated question \ answer, however.. before it gets shut down best way to do it is to have a Windows Service run this for you and to have asynchronous tasks do the work and have an await method

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The name of such pattern is 'scatter/gatter' and it 's rather well described at rabbitmq official site.

Answer (score 1):

the short answer is the "saga" (http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/sagas/) or "process manager" (http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/ProcessManager.html) pattern - which are basically the same thing.

the intention of this pattern is to have a single piece of code that is intelligent. it knows which of the 10 tasks have been sent out, and it waits for all 10 responses. once it receives all 10 responses, it moves on to the next thing that must happen.

how you implement this depends on a lot of things. there are a lot of options, depending on the programming language and libraries you are using.

if you're using nservicebus or masstransit with c#, for example, this pattern is built in.

for more detail on how the pattern works, plus an example in JavaScript (which can be translated into other languages fairly easily), see my blog post here: https://derickbailey.com/2015/08/10/managing-workflow-in-long-running-javascript-processes/